# Dot Net Nuke Ajax call to file.ashx on site root returns 404 error

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, dotnetnuke

I am posting to a file using  ajax in DNN 7.1. The .ashx is on the site root outside of the portals directory. The response is a 404 error and the URL is rewritten to ...com/cart/undefined. I can however put in the following www.mysite.com/cart/cart.ashx and get the expected response.

EDIT

This started by trying to use a .ashx file to call an API. Same code on another site returns 400 with a detailed error message. On the current site the file returns 400 BadRequest and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this issue:

```
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors(v=vs.110).aspx